# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm facing an error with Tensorflow v2.1.0:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter
```

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)

c = a*b

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

File_Writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(r"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TensorFlow\graph", sess.graph)

print(sess.run(c))
```

The output error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-898c56a41b1a> in <module>
      6 sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
      7 
----> 8 File_Writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(r"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\TensorFlow\graph", sess.graph)
      9 
     10 print(sess.run(c))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'
```

What shall I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tf.summary.create_file_writer('log_path')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Although the error is no longer there, but it does not create "graph" folder with a file that I need to run it with tensorboard.